# Getting the latest record from the collection of documents in MonogDB using MongoTemplate

Tags: java, mongodb

I am a newbie to the MongoDB, I have some issues in getting the latest record from the collection of documents using MongoTemplate in Spring MVC.
In the mongo shell, I was able to get the result by executing the following query.

```
db.patients.find().sort({dateOfBirth: -1}).limit().pretty()
```

But I do not know how to achieve the same in my java class using the MongoTemplate. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the following

```
Query query = new Query();
    query.limit(1);
    query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "dateOfBirth"));

    mongoOperation.find(query, Patients.class);
```

note that i set 1 in limit. so it will return only 1 record.

Comment: I think you can use findOne instead of setting the limit to 1.

Comment: yes that is also a good option. The only thing i tried was to give a true translation of what his mongodb raw query looked like. but yes findOne is good if we are targeting for only  1 record.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Satish:-)

Answer (score 2):

Now the Sort constructor made to private. You can't do that any more 
Still you can use as below

```
    Query query = new Query();
    query.limit(1);
    query.with(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC,"_id"));
    return Optional.of(mongoTemplate.findOne(query, RootPath.class));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
db.patients.aggregate([
{$sort:{dateOfBirth: -1}},
{$limit:3}
])
```

> This will give the sort output of dateofbirth in the descending order and it will show only three records out of all. I hope this helps